# Delphi - comparing array to string

Tags: arrays, delphi

Alright I'm remaking this topic from scratch to make everything clear for people who want to help me.

I'm converting numbers to letters (e.g 100 = one hundred) from http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/a/curr2words.htm, however it seems like the algorithm have a lot of bugs.

I'm fixing them one by one, I came across something that I'm unable to fix:

Basically if you type "2 000 000" it will give you "two million, thousand" instead of "two million" only.
If I write "2 000 000 000" it will give you "two billion , million , thousand" instead of "two billion" only.

For what comes to when I write the millions case, I was able to fix it using this:

```
function ArrayToString(const Data: array of string): string;
       var
       SL: TStringList;
       S: string;
begin
SL := TStringList.Create;
try
for S in Data do
  SL.Add(S);
  Result := SL.Text;
finally
  SL.Free;
end;
 end;
 begin

 if ((ArrayToString(splitted[I]) <> (' thousand' + AnsiString(#13#10))))   then
       LettreFinal :=LettreFinal + splitted[I];
```

Using the code above  gets ' thousand' removed from the string (for Billions case or millions case) but I also want to remove ' million' using the same code as above and I tried this:

```
  if ((ArrayToString(splitted[I]) <> (' thousand' + AnsiString(#13#10))) or (ArrayToString(splitted[I]) <> (' million' + AnsiString(#13#10))))  then
       LettreFinal :=LettreFinal + splitted[I];
```

Using the code above don't remove thousand and don't remove million too so It's basically useless (Splitted is basically the string splitted by `,`).

Comment: Hard to know what you mean. Please show [mcve] and the expected output

Comment: Well, *assuming that the string is* what you've shown, *' mille' + AnsiString(#13#10)* isn't in *one million thousand*, which could explain why your code isn't working.

Comment: I just translated mille is thousand in english . first code is working just fine , however I want to take off ' million' as-well but it's not working . (second code not working) .

Comment: If you'd posted a [mcve] you'd have an answer. If you do so now we can reopen and answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following modifications to the original `NumberToWords` unit.

In

```
  function DoHundreds(const NumStr: string): string;
```

add the marked line

```
  begin
    Result := '';   // Add this ************
    sLocNum := NumStr;
```

and in the main body of

```
function ConvertToWords(const Number: double; UseCurrency: Boolean): string;
```

add the marked lines

```
  for iCount := 0 to slValSections.Count - 1 do
    begin
      sSectionVal := '';
      sSectionVal := DoHundreds(slValSections[iCount]);
      if iCount > 0 then
        if sSectionVal <> '' then       // Add this condition **************
          Result := sSectionVal + Suffix[iCount] + Result
        else                            // and this *********
      else
        Result := sSectionVal
    end;
```